# Add link code to this bottom code

Tags: html

Haw can i add a link to this code ?

```
<span style="background-color:#81d742;">Title</span>
```

this code is for a bottom in a website and i want it to have a link .

Thank you

Comment: use this code <a href="your link" >Title</a>

Comment: <a href="#">some <spanstyle="background-color:#81d742;">text</span></a>

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to put `a` tags inside `span`

```html
<span style="background-color:#81d742;"><a href="http://google.com">Title</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a `<span>`? You can just change the tag to a `<a>` tag:

```html
<a style="background-color:#81d742;" href="http//mysite.com">Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do so by using anchor tag, i.e. a tag

For example, if you wish to link google.co, you can do so by following commands,

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```